# why separate assignments are better than single?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I've read that:

> It is more gas efficient to initialize a tightly packed struct with separate assignments instead of a single assignment. Separate assignments makes it easier for the optimizer to update all the variables at once.

So, they say:

this is better:

```js
Point storage p = Point()
p.x = 0;
p.y = 0;
```

Than

```js
Point storage p = Point(0, 0);
```

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with addressing storage. Let's break it down.

Consider a bool and an address. The bool takes 1 byte (limitation of optimization) and the address takes 20 bytes. So we need 21 bytes of storage. The EVM uses 32-byte words which are the smallest chunk of storage that is addressable.

If you go

```
contract A {
  mapping(uint => bool) b;
  mapping(uint => address) a;
}
```

`a` and `b` values live in separate "slots" and you can be accessed them individually. For this to work, all of the storage in a "slot" needs to be allocated for one value, so there is leftover space and it is twice as expensive to store as:

```
contract A {

  struct Stuff {
    bool b;
    address a;
  }

  mapping(uint => Stuff) stuff;
```

Here, the compiler will look at the struct layout and work it out so one 32-byte word that holds 21-bytes of useful information. Of course, if you only want to update one member, then there is a read (to get the other) so the 32-byte write doesn't stomp on the other value.

Conceptually (not a technical explanation of the internals), something like this

```
Stuff storage s = Stuff[<uint>];
s.b = true;
```

makes the compiler

1. compute the slot
2. fetch the word
3. replace the bool with true
4. write the word

Tight packing is usually what you want because the *total* cost to write both a bool and an address is half of writing separate words. Words are the smallest unit of data for the expensive SSTORE opcode. So, yes, in a manner of speaking, structs help the compiler optimize the storage layout for gas cost.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rob, I might have missed your answer. I came across it today. I understand how things are stored in storage. What i don't understand is why initializing struct like this Point(0,0) is less optimized then Point() and then writing variables one by one ? can you show the compiler's look at those 2 difference examples ? Thank you